# Detecting array.... and device error

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, windows-error-reporting

I had the "Error code 0xc00000e A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed. " error on my PC. To fix it , a website recommended that I go to BIOS setup and change the SATA configuration.

Complying to the suggestion, I switched from "RAID" to "non-RAID". After that I restarted the PC it shows a prolonged "Detecting array..." message. Not only that but it doesn't allow me to enter BIOS setup again.

Could you please provide a way how to get out of this double mess? Both the error and the "detecting array..." thing. Thank you in advance

Comment: Imho it doesn't make sense to think about a Windows problem, as long as you have a hardware problem - please edit the question once you solved the BIOS problem with the mainboard's support team.

Comment: @Furty thank you for the advice but who are "the mainboard support team"?

Comment: If your PC has for example a Dell logo on it: contact Dell. If a noname PC: don't you have a manual for your mainboard? Is a manufacturer displayed when you press <kbd>Win-Pause</kbd>? Otherwise check your invoice for hardware details or contact the store where you purchased the machine.